# "Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token" when it should be a ;

Tags: java

So I have this line

```
String line = null;
```

And right after that I have a if statement what it tells me the error is

> Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

So it's saying instead of the ";" there should be a "{".

Also the program is telling me that I need an extra "}" which is most likely added because of the first problem.

SOLUTION: I had to place the code in a constructor.

```
if (f.exists()) {   
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
          System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/Settings.txt"));
    line = reader.readLine();

} catch (IOException e2) {
  // ... etc....
```

Comment: Show more of your code, please.

Comment: Post all the code please...

Comment: Most likely the issue is with some code preceeding this line

Comment: Sorry about that, added the whole code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got code hanging out in the class which has to be in a method or constructor. You can only have variable and method declarations and declarations with assignments in the class, but not non-declarative statements such as...

```
if (f.exists()) {   
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
              System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/Settings.txt"));
        line = reader.readLine();

    } catch (IOException e2) {
      // ... etc....
```

hanging out naked in the class. Put it in a constructor perhaps.

Comment: Placing the code in a constructor solves the problem, thank you for that.

Comment: You can put it with {} too

Comment: @nachokk: yep, 1+ to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add curly braces, this will be executed when you creates a new object, after parent constructor before this constructor. But is not nice , you can put it in methods and constructors as @HovercraftFullOfEels suggested

```
    { // here new
    if (f.exists()) {

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/Settings.txt"));
            line = reader.readLine();

        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e2.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Code: Bx001", "Error", 0);

        }
        //System.out.println(line);

        Shared.enableHotKey = line.substring (0, line.indexOf("!"));

        Shared.key1 = line.substring(line.indexOf("!") + 1, line.indexOf("@"));

        Shared.key2 = line.substring(line.indexOf("@") + 1, line.indexOf("#"));

        Shared.key3 = line.substring(line.indexOf("#")  + 1, line.indexOf("$"));

        Shared.startUpMessage = line.substring(line.indexOf("$") + 1);

        System.out.println(Shared.enableHotKey + " " + Shared.key1 + " " + Shared.key2 + " " + Shared.key3 + " " + Shared.startUpMessage);
    } else {
        Shared.startUpMessage = "true";
    }

 }// here new
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are new to java programming language (object oriented) so you are doing this mistake.

You should put these things inside the function.

So, it may look like:

```
package org.maple.mapleshot;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CheckSettings {

public void check(){

BufferedReader reader;

File f = new File (System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/Settings.txt");

String line = null;

if (f.exists()) {

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/Settings.txt"));
        line = reader.readLine();

    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e2.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Code: Bx001", "Error", 0);

    }
    //System.out.println(line);

    Shared.enableHotKey = line.substring (0, line.indexOf("!"));

    Shared.key1 = line.substring(line.indexOf("!") + 1, line.indexOf("@"));

    Shared.key2 = line.substring(line.indexOf("@") + 1, line.indexOf("#"));

    Shared.key3 = line.substring(line.indexOf("#")  + 1, line.indexOf("$"));

    Shared.startUpMessage = line.substring(line.indexOf("$") + 1);

    System.out.println(Shared.enableHotKey + " " + Shared.key1 + " " + Shared.key2 + " " + Shared.key3 + " " + Shared.startUpMessage);
} else {
    Shared.startUpMessage = "true";
}
}

}
```

Don't worry about these things. Just do more practice and you will get more familiar with java.